# how to test prefetch/prerender

Tags: html, testing, prefetch, prerender

I have started to load a few key resources and pages using the prefetch/prerender system.

Is there a way to ensure that the resources in question are actually being preloaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google recommends using the [Page Visibility API](https://w3c.github.io/page-visibility/) to test if a page is being prerendered.  I'm not sure how well it works cross-browser (but what does in HTML5).

Answer (score 14):

You can also use [prerender-test.appspot.com](http://prerender-test.appspot.com) to test that your site works correctly under prerendering. Further, from within Chrome, you can go to `chrome://net-internals#prerender` to see a list of attempted prerenders and whether they were used, and if they were not used, why they were canceled.

Comment: This seems like it should be the accepted answer. `chrome://net-internals#prerender` is definitely the best way to test this.

Comment: @pseudosavant If it says Prerender Enabled: false go to Settings->advanced-> Privacy/check the prerender box