# Prefetching images on dynamically generated pages

Tags: php, html, get, google-chrome-devtools, prefetch

HTML5 Prefetching is a great tool and in the past it's provided a users with a much better user experience when navigate image galleries. Though, in this case I can't seem to get my images to preload properly. When I view the network tab in Chrome dev tools I see that of the GET requests are processed but under status they are listed as (canceled) & type is "Pending".

Any idea why these requests would get canceled?

I'm using a basic PHP for loop to iterate through a JSON array to retrieve the image paths you can see that here:

```
 <?php foreach($this->slideShow as $key => $value ) {?>
    <link rel="prefetch" href="<?= $value->mainImage ?>">
 <?php } ?>
```

Here is an example of what is returned when the above loop runs:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://cdnl.mysite.com/mp/620/400/leadimage1.jpg">
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://cdnl.mysite.com/mp/620/400/leadimage2.jpg">
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://cdnl.mysite.com/mp/620/400/leadimage3.jpg">
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://cdnl.mysite.com/mp/620/400/leadimage4.jpg">
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://cdnl.mysite.com/mp/620/400/leadimage5.jpg">
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431366/how-to-test-prefetch-prerender

Comment: It seems this feature is not quite ready for Prime Time: http://www.rocketmill.co.uk/html5-prefetch

Comment: @Diodeus - that link is discussing page prerendering; the OP's question is about resource prefetching.   They are related, but different.

Answer (score 0):

The prefetches are cancelled because the developer tools are opened. If you use the `chrome://net-internals` tool, you'll see that they succeed when the dev tools are closed. The cancelled prefetches are noisy, but nothing is wrong.

Comment: why would they be canceled because the devtools were opened? what is the logic in that?